# how to prove the following integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Hi I was trying without success to prove the following, any ideas how?
$$
\frac d{dx}\int_a^{e^x}f(t)dt=e^x\cdot f(e^x)
$$

Comment: **F**undamental **T**heorem of **C**alculus, may be

Comment: Let $F(x):=\int_a^xf(t)dt$. If $f$ is continuous, $\frac{dF}{dx}=f$.

Now, you want to take the derivative of $\int_a^{e^x}f(t)dt=F(e^x)$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells that $$\frac d{dx}\,\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, dt=f\big(b(x)\big) b'(x)-f\big(a(x)\big) a'(x)$$ Just apply.